# Python Pandas Dataframe: length of index does not match - df['column'] = ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, valueerror

I have a pandas Dataframe containing EOD financial data (OHLC) for analysis.

I'm using https://github.com/cirla/tulipy library to generate technical indicator values, that have a certain timeperiod as option. For Example. ADX with timeperiod=5 shows ADX for last 5 days.

Because of this timeperiod, the generated array with indicator values is always shorter in length than the Dataframe. Because the prices of first 5 days are used to generate ADX for day 6..

```
    pdi14, mdi14 = ti.di(
    high=highData, low=lowData, close=closeData, period=14)

    df['mdi_14'] = mdi14
    df['pdi_14'] = pdi14
    >> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Unfortunately, unlike TA-LIB for example, this tulip library does not provide NaN-values for these first couple of empty days...

Is there an easy way to prepend these NaN to the ndarray?
Or insert into df at a certain index & have it create NaN for the rows before it automatically?

Thanks in advance, I've been researching for days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe make the shift yourself in the code ?

```
period = 14
pdi14, mdi14 = ti.di(
    high=highData, low=lowData, close=closeData, period=period
)

df['mdi_14'] = np.NAN
df['mdi_14'][period - 1:] = mdi14
```

I hope they will fill the first values with NAN in the lib in the future. It's dangerous to leave time series data like this without any label.

Comment: Thanks!! this worked. I expect Full MCVE to work too but this was a little easier to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Full MCVE

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, range(10), list('ABC'))

a = np.full((len(df) - 6, df.shape[1]), 2)
b = np.full((6, df.shape[1]), np.nan)

c = np.row_stack([b, a])

d = pd.DataFrame(c, df.index, df.columns)
d

     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  2.0  2.0  2.0
7  2.0  2.0  2.0
8  2.0  2.0  2.0
9  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The C version of the [tulip library](https://tulipindicators.org/) includes a `start` function for each indicator (reference: https://tulipindicators.org/usage) that can be used to determine the output length of an indicator given a set of input options. Unfortunately, it does not appear that the python bindings library, [tulipy](https://github.com/cirla/tulipy), includes this functionality. Instead you have to resort to dynamically reassigning your index values to align the output with the original DataFrame.

Here is an example that uses the price series from the tulipy docs:

```
#Create the dataframe with close prices
prices = pd.DataFrame(data={81.59, 81.06, 82.87, 83, 83.61, 83.15, 82.84, 83.99, 84.55,
 84.36, 85.53, 86.54, 86.89, 87.77, 87.29}, columns=['close'])

#Compute the technical indicator using tulipy and save the result in a DataFrame
bbands = pd.DataFrame(data=np.transpose(ti.bbands(real = prices['close'].to_numpy(), period = 5, stddev = 2)))

#Dynamically realign the index; note from the tulip library documentation that the price/volume data is expected be ordered "oldest to newest (index 0 is oldest)"
bbands.index += prices.index.max() - bbands.index.max()

#Put the indicator values with the original DataFrame
prices[['BBANDS_5_2_low', 'BBANDS_5_2_mid', 'BBANDS_5_2_up']] = bbands
prices.head(15)

close   BBANDS_5_2_low  BBANDS_5_2_mid  BBANDS_5_2_up
0   81.06   NaN NaN NaN
1   81.59   NaN NaN NaN
2   82.87   NaN NaN NaN
3   83.00   NaN NaN NaN
4   83.61   80.530042   82.426  84.321958
5   83.15   81.494061   82.844  84.193939
6   82.84   82.533343   83.094  83.654657
7   83.99   82.471983   83.318  84.164017
8   84.55   82.417750   83.628  84.838250
9   84.36   82.435203   83.778  85.120797
10  85.53   82.511331   84.254  85.996669
11  86.54   83.142618   84.994  86.845382
12  86.89   83.536488   85.574  87.611512
13  87.77   83.870324   86.218  88.565676
14  87.29   85.288871   86.804  88.319129
```